# R shiny file upload, attending function

Tags: r, file-upload, shiny

I want to set up a little shiny app to simplify the usage of one of my functions. So the function I want to use is

```
create_rating <- function(data_path, x, y, z)
```

Input is `String, int, int int`
Output is a `matrix`

```
library(shiny)
library(NLP)

create_rating <- function(data_path, x, y, z){}

ui <- fluidPage(

   titlePanel("Review"),
   sidebarLayout(
     sidebarPanel(
       fileInput("file1", "Choose .txt File",
                 accept=c("text/csv", 
                          "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain")),
       actionButton("update", "Upload!"),
       hr(),

       numericInput("good", "3* Rating",15),
       numericInput("ok", "2* Rating",8),
       numericInput("bad", "1* Rating",3)    
     ),
     mainPanel(
       h4("Review"),
       tableOutput("result_shiny")
     )
   )

)

server <- function(input, output) {
    inFile <- reactive({input$file1})
    if(is.null(inFile()))
    return(NULL)

    x <- reactive({input$good})
    y <- reactive({input$ok})
    z <- reactive({input$bad})

    result <- reactive({
      input$update
        withProgress({
          setProgress(message = "Processing review...")
          physical_check(as.String(path), x(), y(), z())
        })
      })

    output$result_shiny <- renderTable({result()})  
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Then it opens a Window, layout fits but it is showing the processing notification all the time and no result.

Or i tried the server part like

```
server <- function(input, output) {
      output$result_shiny <- eventReactive(input$update,{
      inFile <- reactive({input$file1})
      x <- reactive({input$good})
      y <- reactive({input$ok})
      z <- reactive({input$bad})
      resultat <- reactive({
        withProgress({
          setProgress(message = "Processing review...")
          physical_check(as.String(inFile()$datapath), x(), y(), z())
        })
      })

    })

}
```

But with this function, it opens the window, I can choose a file, push the Upload button and nothing, also no processing notification.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the server part of your function  by adding a condition `if(!is.null(inFile()))`so that the function `create_rating`(I am assuming that you were referring to function `create_rating` and not `physical_check` as there is no such function defined anywhere in your code) be called  only after the file has been uploaded.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  inFile <- reactive({input$file1})

  x <- reactive({input$good})
  y <- reactive({input$ok})
  z <- reactive({input$bad})
  observe({
    if(!is.null(inFile())){
      result <- reactive({
        input$update
        withProgress({
          setProgress(message = "Processing review...")
          create_rating(as.String(path), x(), y(), z())
        })
      })
      output$result_shiny <- renderTable({result()})  
    }

  })

}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, is working fine. Although I'm not sure, why Shiny is not accepting my attempt.